# Why TToolBar doesn't want to wrap?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-2009

I put a `TToolBar` on my form and add some `TSpeedButton`. I ensure myself that `Wrapable` is set to true and run the application. But when I shrink the form the buttons don't wrap on new line. What am I missing ? I am using Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `TToolBar.AutoSize` to `True`, and add separators between groups of buttons so there's a place for it to split the toolbar into sections.

It's also better to use `TToolButton` on the `TToolBar` instead, as it's designed to work with them. Right-click the toolbar and choose `New Button` or `New Separator`. Assign the images you want to display to a `TImageList`, and assign the imagelist to the `TToolbar.Images` property, then set the `ImageIndex` for each button to display an image from the list. (Another advantage is that you can also separate imagelists to the `HotImages` and `DisabledImages` properties as well.)